I can't start the MSSQLSERVER on new esxi host
I am a student currently studying virtualization and SQL. After obtaining approval from my instructor, I attempted to transfer a virtual machine (VM) to my personal laptop.
However, upon doing so, I encountered issues with its functionality. Regrettably, my instructor was unable to offer assistance in resolving the problem.. When I logged into the virtual machine on my laptop, I noticed that some services weren’t running. These services were running fine on the original host where I exported the virtual machine from.
services that stopped running :
Service           Discription                         Status
-------           ------------                        -------
SQLSERVERAGENT    SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)      stopped
Netlogon          Netlogon                            stopped
MSSQLSERVER       SQL Server                          stopped

When attempting to start the services, the following issues arise:
Netlogon Throws no error but the statuse doesn't change and remains stopped
MSSQLSERVER The error says the service cannot be started either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associeted with it
SQLSERVERAGENT The error says the dependancy service or group failed to start
All I need is to experiment and practice on the database and data , so for that i need somehow to start those services first , any help  would be appreciated.

ESXi is a baremetal hypervisor that has no local console, so when you talk about moving the VM to your laptop, and logging into the VM on the laptop, it sounds like you are not running the VM in ESXI. are you using VMWare Workstation or another desktop virtualization system? also note, without netlogon running, you should not be able to login. how specifically did you transfer the VM to the laptop?

@FrankThomas Well I exported the VM , I am capable of logging into system as the admin without any issue , what I want to do is just to run those services with my admin privillages , anyway I know i could download the db and install a new OS and sql server and deploy it .... but seriously can't it be done on this OS ? I think this could be because of group policies that a specific sytem could run those services ... how to disable all of them .. I went though registery and change value of start of gpsvc to 4 to diable group policy but  no luck ...
